# How do I delay a twilio message from being sent based on user input time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I have been looking everywhere for good documentation for how to send a delayed twilio message. I've found a number of gems but they do not seem to have very good documentation/examples. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to send a delayed message and where I might find some concrete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried looking for a Twilio based example of what you are looking for but also came up dry, so I suggest not looking for a Twilio solution, but rather something more generic. I would perhaps look at delayed_job for ruby. It seems to have what you are after. Most notably it allows you to create jobs that are meant to run at some point in the future.

as for the second part of your question, doing a quick search on the net, I see there are many examples for the above mentioned gem. While you might not find an example specifically pertaining to send a sms at a future date, the generic part is performing a task in the future, what the function does that gets called in the future, is ultimately up to you.